# Submit button action in MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to find out the best way to create a submit and add button action in a controller.

I have a HttpGet for Create (Submit) but not sure how to do a HttpPost or if Get or Post is even needed:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var drafList = _drService.GetDraft().ToList();

    var IndexViewModel = new IndexViewModel();
    IndexViewModel.Draft = draftList;
    IndexViewModel.Published = _drService.GetPublished();
    IndexViewModel.Current = _drService.GetCurrent();

    return View(IndexViewModel);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text- danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="asof">As of:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input name="AsOf" type="date" title="AsOf" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix col-md-12"></div>
            <div class="clearfix col-md-12"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="title">Title:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect when clicking the Add button to perform the actions in the controller and add the record.

Comment: You need to use `asp-for` for your input box.Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a controller action with the same name (create() in this case) but with the [httpPost] prefix on the action so that the form would call the post create action when submitted

Answer (score 0):

GET is for non-destructive actions, i.e. the same GET request should return the same response when repeated. For a create, you need to use a POST. Basically, you need to add an action like:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IndexViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    // map the data posted (`model`) onto your entity class
    var entity = new MyEntity
    {
        Foo = model.Foo,
        Bar = model.Bar
    };

    _context.Add(entity);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```